# transpose columns into rows, keep first column as name

Tags: python, excel, transpose

I hope someone can help me with this. I'm trying to create a database with annual report data. I have data from finance.yahoo which provides the data into columns per year, where the first column is the name of the row.

[image]

What I want to end up with is a database with the following columns: Company, year, company_account, value. So in essence I want the data from multiple columns transposed to 1 column while keeping the first column as column name.

[image]

My goal is to do this for many companies so I can compare them for research purpose. Although I'm not an computer scientist I have a basic understanding of SQL, Python and Excel. So any solutions involving these tools would be great. Any other solutions are also welcome!

Comment: Excel and SQL are different beasts, and you should really be asking your question only for one technology.

Comment: You should be able to do that with Power Query or VBA. BTW, your screenshot of data is virtually useless for doing proper testing. It cannot be copy/pasted into a worksheet. One can try an OCR program, or manually enter it. Having to do either of these is discouraging to those who might assist you. To make the data useful edit your question to post it as text, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables), or possibly upload a workbook (with sensitive information removed) to some public website and post a link in your original question